# c# how to set the styling of a gridview text field to 2 options: with hyperlink and without

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, hyperlink

I have a code for a gridview feild that displays a title, and evaluates a hyperlink (link) in a way that if there is a value in the link, that title will be clickable and the title will redirect you to the link.. as followed:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                <ItemTemplate >    
               <asp:HyperLink ID="Title"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("link") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>            
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The code is working fine, but the title is currently black. I need to style the title in a way that if there is a link, it will be blue and undelined, else it will be black.

I'm using C#/aspx in here.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Title"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("link") %>' style='<%# Eval("link").ToString()!=""? "text-decoration:underline;color:Blue;":""%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```